# Golang Even Odd print variable using sync.Cond

Tags: go, concurrency

I am learning more about concurrency in Golang.
I am trying to print even-odd numbers using 2 different threads. I know printing even-odd more about synchronization/sequential access of shared resources than concurrency, still worth trying.

I know it can be done using channel or by using waitgroup and I have already done it but still trying to achieve same thing using sync.cond.

In the below code if **I enable the last fmt.Println** in both function then it print more than 10 number but if I comment it and enable **first fmt.Print function** then it works fine. Its very strange output.
I am not able to understand why this is happening can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var done bool

func odd(name *int, c *sync.Cond) {
    //fmt.Println(*name, "ODD ")
    if *name >= 9 {
        return
    }
    c.L.Lock()
    for !done {
        c.Wait()
    }
    *name++
    done = false
    fmt.Println(*name, "ODD")
    c.L.Unlock()
    c.Signal()
}

func even(name *int, c *sync.Cond) {

    //fmt.Println(*name, "EVEN ")
    if *name >= 9 {
        return
    }
    c.L.Lock()
    for done == true {
        c.Wait()
    }
    done = true
    *name++
    fmt.Println(*name, "EVEN ")
    c.L.Unlock()
    c.Signal()
}

func main() {
    done = false

    cond := sync.NewCond(&sync.Mutex{})
    val := 0
    for val < 10 {
        go odd(&val, cond)
        go even(&val, cond)
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("val final:=  ", val)
}
```

**First output when last print enabled**

1 EVEN 
2 ODD
3 EVEN 
4 ODD
5 EVEN 
6 ODD
7 EVEN 
8 ODD
9 EVEN 
10 ODD
11 EVEN 
12 ODD
13 EVEN 
14 ODD
15 EVEN 
16 ODD
17 EVEN 
18 ODD
19 EVEN 
20 ODD
21 EVEN 
22 ODD
23 EVEN 
24 ODD
25 EVEN 
26 ODD
27 EVEN 
28 ODD
29 EVEN 
30 ODD
31 EVEN 
32 ODD
33 EVEN 
34 ODD
35 EVEN 
36 ODD
37 EVEN 
38 ODD
39 EVEN 
40 ODD
41 EVEN 
42 ODD
43 EVEN 
44 ODD
45 EVEN 
46 ODD 
47 EVEN 
48 ODD
49 EVEN 
50 ODD
val final:=   51

**Output when First print enabled**

0 EVEN
1 ODD 
2 ODD 
4 ODD 
4 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
6 EVEN 
10 ODD 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
10 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 EVEN 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
2 ODD 
2 ODD 
2 ODD 
2 EVEN 
4 ODD 
4 EVEN 
4 ODD 
4 EVEN 
4 ODD 
4 EVEN 
4 ODD 
4 EVEN 
6 EVEN 
6 ODD 
6 EVEN 
6 ODD 
6 EVEN 
8 EVEN 
8 ODD 
8 EVEN 
10 EVEN 
8 EVEN 
10 EVEN 
10 ODD 
10 EVEN 
2 ODD 
10 EVEN 
10 ODD 
2 EVEN 
10 EVEN 
10 EVEN 
val final:=   10

**Link for the Go playground:** 
https://go.dev/play/p/_Kcb_04JiPI

Answer (score 2):

The most glaring issue is with the loop:

```
for val < 10 {
    go odd(&val, cond)
    go even(&val, cond)
}
```

I'm guessing your intent was to start two workers and wait for a termination event (`val` to reach `10`).

Data-races aside, the above is a tight loop which will keep generating multiple (and unnecessary) "odd" and "even" goroutines while it waits for the termination event, creating unpredictable results.

You can see [the the goroutine explosion](https://go.dev/play/p/gHBXwACcefP) by adding this line to the loop:

```
fmt.Println("goroutine #", runtime.NumGoroutine())
```

---

To fix, you need to start a single goroutine for both `odd()` and `even()` and use a "done" channel or [context cancelation](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel) to signal the job is done to all goroutines. This then negates the need to poll `val` - which is a data-race since you are reading it while it is being updated in other goroutine(s) without any coordination on the "read" end.

Comment: My question is still remain same, why and how  print statement is impacting the result ?

Comment: And my answer is still the same: you have multiple goroutines doing duplicate work. The freeing & acquiring of locks is not bouncing between 2 goroutines - odd & even - but many goroutines. Odd to odd, even to even, even to odd. The resulting processing sequence is thus unpredictable. The print statement just adds some noise to the unpredictability.